# How to change the response soap message in javax.xml.rpc.handler.Handler.handleFault(MessageContext ctx)

Tags: soap, soaphandler

I wrote a handler (javax.xml.rpc.handler.Handler) for a SOAP web service that inspects header data. How can I modify the response message when the method **handleFault** is invoked?

```
public class SeguridadHandler implements javax.xml.rpc.handler.Handler {
    ...
    public boolean handleFault(MessageContext context) {
        // modify the response message here
        return true;
    }
    ...

}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public boolean handleFault(MessageContext context) {
    SOAPMessageContext smc = (SOAPMessageContext) context;
}
```

Cast to [SOAPMessageContext](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/ws/handler/soap/SOAPMessageContext.html) and then do whatever you want. Depending on what exactly you need to do also consider using [MessageFactory](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/soap/MessageFactory.html)

Comment: Thanks. I found a full example here: http://www.roseindia.net/javacertification/wsd-guide/saaj_apis.shtml

Answer (score 0):

you can avoid the cast:

```
public class SeguridadHandler implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext> {
    ...
    public boolean handleFault(SOAPMessageContext context) {
        // modify the response message here
        return true;
    }
    ...

}
```